# Android Kotlin checkBox.isChecked is not recoginized by the ide

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to change the state of my check boxes in Android Studio. Everywhere I look, it is telling me to use `isChecked()`, but the ide is not recognizing the method. Am I missing something simple? Is it a problem with the ide version I am using.

```
deleteAlarmCheckBox.isChecked(false)
```

Android Studio 4.1.3
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119, built on March 10, 2021
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

edit: checkbox.isChecked is working in the main activity file. Not sure why it works there but not in the adapter class.

[image: 3rd picture]

[image: second picture]

[image: picture]

Comment: Do you mean `isChecked = false`? Remember you should always check the documentation if you're not sure about some methods. Asking here is probably a waste of your time.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
deleteAlarmCheckBox.isChecked = false // by using property access
```

instead of

```
deleteAlarmCheckBox.isChecked(false) // because there is no setter function as such
```

To use it as a function you should use

```
deleteAlarmCheckBox.setChecked(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

`deleteAlarmCheckBox` is recognised as a `View` of some kind, but if it doesn't have `isChecked` as a function in the autocomplete, then it's not been declared as a [Checkable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable) type - i.e. one of the widgets that implements the `Checkable` interface (which is where the `isChecked` method comes from).

Either the widget in the layout isn't a `Checkable` one (like a `Checkbox`, or a `MaterialButton` that's been given the `android:checkable="true"` attribute in XML), or the `deleteAlarmCheckBox` property in your `ViewHolder` is declared as some non-`Checkable` type, so the type system doesn't know it's checkable.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It helped point me in the right direction.

Comment: if you are curious as to what it was, i posted an answer with a picture.

Answer (score 0):

I changed some things in the `onBindViewHolder` method. Check out the picture to see what I changed, in the comment stuff is what I had.

[image: picture]

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like `deleteAlarmCheckBox.isChecked = false`

If you see the documentation in IDE itself you can see you can use it both as setter or getter, if you assign something it will be setter and if you are accessing something it will be getter.

[image]

Comment: I have tried it the way you mentioned, but it is still not being recognized as anything. I put in a second picture of it. there is nothing in the autofill suggestions with anything that has isChecked in it. Its like it does not exist.

Comment: it can't be are you sure that your deleteCheckbox is indeed of Checkbox type